# Connect node.js and java through sockets

Tags: java, node.js, http, sockets, server

I'm trying to connect to my server (which runs `nodejs` with `sockets.io`) from my Java client. I want it to detect whenever the client reaches the server and print something to the console.

After the connection is successful, 2nd step would be to the client to be able to send a string to the server via sockets.

I run the JAVA code but the server is not detecting the client connection and I don't understand why is that happening and I can't find good resources for sockets communication with nodejs.

server-side code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(65432, () => {
        console.log('listening on *:65432');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('connection successfull');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('send coordinates', function(data){
                console.log('a user connected');
        });
});

console.log('listening to port');
```

Client side code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    String str = "Hello World";
    try {
        socket = new Socket(**[serverIP]**, 65432);
        osw =new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        osw.write(str, 0, str.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `http` module, as one might be able to guess from its name, implements HTTP: when it receives a request _in HTTP format_, it processes the request by passing to code (in your case using `express`) which generates a response _in HTTP format_. Your Java code is not sending an HTTP request. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).